# Does creating one system restore points everyday damage my hard disk?

Tags: restore, system-restore

I have a habit of creating a one system restore points every day. Will it cause any damage to my hard disk?

System restore points referring to C Drive only, not all drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm in creating system restore points.

System restore points are extremely beneficial.  They allow you to roll back to the time they were created, in case a system upgrade goes wrong, you are infected with a virus, or fix other negative affects that might make your system unresponsive.

There is one case where some people may say creating lots system restore points in a negative:  Solid state disks (SSD).  Solid state disks do have limited write cycles and will *eventually* wear out.  However, modern SSDs have extremely long lifespans and an "everyday user" will more than likely replace the drive long before the drive starts failing.

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't damage your drive, unless you reach the storage limit. If you decide to overwrite data, although you shouldn't, then you would lose data.

Comment: In your answer, please explain how it will damage the drive if they reach the storage limit.